# HTML layout techniques (for admin panel)

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I am creating an admin panel from scratch and I would like to know what techniques there are for me to utilize in order to minimize the need for duplicate code (especially for HTML).

A way back I just re-wrote all of HTML in every single file. While this gave the ultimate modifiability for single pages the amount of work and maintenance makes it the worst way to go.

Many years ago I started doing incorporating PHP into the HTML via functions like:

```
PrintMenu();
PrintHeader();
PrintLeftBox();
```

While this shortened the need for code it made future alterations of the page too complex. What if I wanted to change the whole layout and remove left box from the HTML? Now I have hundreds of pages full of PrintLeftBox();

These two simple ways are pretty much only ways I have ever created a website layout.

Now I'm looking for a much more dynamic and efficient way to product a layout that can be modified per page and be redone easily.

Most of my pages will look the same; menu on the top, huge content on the middle and a footer on the bottom. While some of the sites will require different kind of setup; a menu on the top, some sort of navigation on the left, a list of items on the middle and possibly an "edit view" on the right.

How can I create a "layout system" that can work with pages that look different?

I don't need any code, I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that having a hundred pages with PrintMenu() is a good thing, in that you only need to change the content of that function to update the look of hundreds of pages, at least as long as you are sure that all pages use the menu. Now maybe if you passed an argument, let's say an array (so that you can update its properties later on) which contains for instance the page characteristics, then this would make a more flexible model. 
Or you could pass an object too if you so wanted.

```
pageConfig = new oPageConfig

PrintMenu (pageConfig);
PrintHeader (pageConfig);
PrintLeftBox (pageConfig);
```

Also passing a variable to your functions, you could choose to not display a menu (for a special page with no menu for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Template Engine** can be quite helpeful under this situation. 
Choose one of the following two solutions as you like.

1. in backend, try Jade(Node.js), TWIG(PHP)...

   You can find more here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines;

   The `Menu`, `Header`, `Footer` will be seperated in different files, and can be **included** in other html files which will be rendered by template engine at **server** part.
2. in frontend, try Angular.js or other web MVC frameworks,

   the disadvantage of this solution is that you may need spend more time on providing a stable restful api, because all the rendering works are finished by the Angular.js at **client** part.